# The variable animacao of Controles has not been assigned

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my character walk in one `animation` and stand still in the other `animation`.

In `Animator`, I created a parameter of type `float` **andar** to do the control of exchange between the animations as shown in the image below.

[image]

---

And assigning the following conditions to the arrows:

*andar > 0.1 = personagem;
*andar < 0.1 = personagemStop;

Example of one of the arrows:

[image]

---

My javascript code:

```
#pragma strict

var speed : float;
var personagem : GameObject;
var animacao : Animator;


function Start () {
    speed = 2;
}


function Update () {
    transform.position.x += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    //THE ERROR OCCURS IN "andar"!!!!!_________________________________________
    animacao.SetFloat("andar",Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")));
    //________________________________________________________________

    if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0){
        personagem.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = Vector2(0,180);
    }
    else if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0){
        personagem.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = Vector2(0,0);
    }
}
```

---

Maybe it might be something related to the **Unity version**

I was following this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuqGIB8j7E

My Unity version = 5.3.1f1
Unity tutorial version = 4.3.2f1

---

**Error:**

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable animacao of Controles has
>   not been assigned. You probably need to assign the animacao variable
>   of the Controles script in the inspector.
>   UnityEngine.Animator.SetFloat (System.String name, Single value)
>   Controles.Update () (at Assets/Assets/Scripts/Controles.js:17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer  is simple, you need to drag & drop the object holding the animator into the `animacao` field of the script, in the inspector. Otherwise, your script does not know which animator to use.

In fact, it's not shown in the video, it has been done during the black screen around 5:28.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test tonight and warn you.